# Embedded Unity within my App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-library, arcore

I'm trying to build an AR project in Unity and use it as a library in my native android app. 
I used this article as a guideline:
https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

I successfully imported the project to Android Studio, but the **settings.gradle file is missing**.

Although I can run the project from the studio, when I convert it to a library and use its aar file in my native android app - I fail to build the project.

Has anyone succeeded doing it?

Comment: Very interesting. Have you made any progress yet?

Comment: I followed that guide to embedded Unity project into Android native using UnityPlayerActivity and **it worked**. Altough **Camera is not working** on Android build... Anyone with the same issue? Are you importing the UnityPlayerActivity from your generated package instead the default?

Answer (score 3):

I followed the guideline and it worked out. I put the `.aar` file below the native app libs file. In app `build.gradle`, under dependencies add:

```
implementation(name:"AndroidPluginDemo",ext:"aar")
```

and under android add

```
repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs' //this way we can find the .aar file in libs folder
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you tested with a Camera? On my Unity canvas I added a SnackBar and a Button and they are working on Android build, but I got no image from Camera..

Comment: Are you able to find UnityPlayerActivity within your activity?  I have also followed above guidelines and gradle synced successfully but not able to call UnityPlayer class within my project. Please help,I'm stuck in this for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the above answers asking about the camera not working, the problem for me was the one of the classes in the unity app wasn't being found when i imported that library into my android app.

When you're converting the application to a library project, take note in the build.gradle of the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation(name: 'vlsdk', ext:'aar')
```

}

In my case I had to find the 'vlsdk.aar' file that was being referenced, and import that as a new module (as is done in step 6 of the tutorial) into my native android app. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old and i hope you have found a solution. but to anyone else facing this issue.

Add the ".aar" libraries found in the libs folder of unity's exported project to the build.gradle file as dependencies(they also need to be physically present in the native projects libs folder).
In my case when i built the .aar library from the exported project it did not add the dependencies(unity exported project also has dependencies found in the libs folder). I only excluded the "unity-classes.jar" file as my unity code is already in the ".aar" that i created.

Check the following link

https://medium.com/@randive.rishiraj/7-steps-to-integrate-google-arcore-unity-project-to-a-native-android-app-d85793ba0b37

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Unity features inside native apps we need to change Unity Project as a library, and then integrate inside our native application.
From version 2019.3.a2 Unity introduced a new feature Unity as a library in native apps both Android and Ios.

Steps:

**1. Export Unity Project as an Library (Android)**

**2. Add Unity Library Module inside Native Android Project**

**3.Show Unity View inside Android Activity**

Previously, the exported Unity project will have only one gradle module and one manifest file.
But now the Structure has been changed to two gradle modules.

**1. launcher**

**2.unityLibrary**

Both launcher and unityLibrary module will have its own build.gradle and manifest files.

> **unityLibrary** - module will have Unity runtime and project data, it can be easily integrated into any other gradle project. It will help
> to integrate Unity inside our native android project.
>
> **launcher** - module will have all icons and the application name.

But we want use only **unityLibrary** module as an library inside our native android project.

This blog helps to implement unity view in your native android app.

https://navinkumar0118.medium.com/show-unity-view-inside-native-android-app-8035b9b6895a